# Como comparar todas as posições de um array em PHP

Tags: php, array

Preenchi meus dois arrays que preciso comparar perfeitamente, porem não consigo comparar todas as posições... Esse é o caso:

```
foreach($periodo as $data){
    $arrayDiasSemestre[] = $data->format("w");
}          

include_once 'classes/professoresclass.php';    

if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); } 

$idSemestre = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];

$oProfessor = new professoresclass();
$oProfessor ->listarDisponibilidade4($idSemestre);

while ($arrayDisp = mysql_fetch_array($oProfessor->retorno())){
    if ($arrayDisp['dia'] == $arrayDiasSemestre[]) {
        echo $arrayDisp['idP'];
    }
}
```

O problema é o `$arrayDiasSemestre[]`... Como eu poderia fazer para que ele passasse por todas as posições desse array comparando item por item?

Comment: O que tem `$arrayDisp['dia']`? Pode dar um exemplo de conteudo?

Comment: Ainda acho que valia a pena responder á pergunta nos comentários, para clarificar a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque um foreach depois do while para fazer a comparação de cada linha que vem com o banco para cada valor de `$arrayDiasSemestre`.

```
while ($arrayDisp = mysql_fetch_array($oProfessor->retorno())){
    foreach($arrayDiasSemestre as $item){
       if ($arrayDisp['dia'] == $item) {
          echo $arrayDisp['idP'];
    }
}
```

Pode usar tabém a função [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) que retonar um boolean se o valor existe ou não.

```
while ($arrayDisp = mysql_fetch_array($oProfessor->retorno())){
   if(in_array($arrayDisp['dia'], arrayDiasSemestre)){
      echo $arrayDisp['idP'];
   }
}
```

Comment: `+1` acho que o caminho é esse, usando o `in_array()`

Comment: Funcionou com o foreach! o in_array deu pau talvez pq o item de comparação é outro array daí deu erro, mas como o foreach funcionou então blz! Valeu!!

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente, *comparar perfeitamente* seria comparar chave e valor de um array. Para isso, você pode usar [**array_diff_assoc**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php) para *computar a diferença entre arrays com checagem adicional de índice*, para verificar os valores e as chaves d eum array.

<sub>1) Um array com valor não esperado: **output: array( [1] => value4 )**</sub>

```
$_array = array( 'value1' , 'value2' , 'value3' );
$arrays = array( 'value1' , 'value4' , 'value3' );
$result = array_diff_assoc( $arrays , $_array );
print_r( $result );
```

---

<sub>2) Um array com valores fora de ordem: **output: array( [1] => value3 , [2] => value2 )**</sub>

```
$_array = array( 'value1' , 'value2' , 'value3' );
$arrays = array( 'value1' , 'value3' , 'value2' );
$result = array_diff_assoc( $arrays , $_array );
print_r( $result );
```

---

<sub>3) Um array com chaves e valores iguais: **output: array()**</sub>

```
$_array = array( 'value1' , 'value2' , 'value3' );
$arrays = array( 'value1' , 'value2' , 'value3' );
$result = array_diff_assoc( $arrays , $_array );
print_r( $result );
```

Exemplo no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/cwNagW) .

---

> [*DOC*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php):
>   `array_diff_assoc( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )`
>
> Compara array1 com array2 e retorna a diferença. Ao contrário de array_diff(), **as chaves dos arrays são usadas na comparação**.